# Cómo ajustar este trigger para generar el resultado que describo?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo el siguiente Trigger comento que no tengo mucha experiencia en ello:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insertar_control AFTER UPDATE ON bienes
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Activo = NEW.Activo;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET SubActivo = NEW.SubActivo;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Numero_Empleado = NEW.Numero_Empleado;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Empleado_Movimiento = NEW.Empleado_Movimiento;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Cotejado = NEW.Cotejado;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Proceso = NEW.Proceso;

  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Me base en [Sintaxis Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) , lo que pretendo realizar es lo siguiente, en cierto momento del sistema se actualizan dos campos de la tabla bienes, al momento que estos sean actualizados, se dispare el trigger y haga una copia de los campos que se han indicado en el trigger y estos sean insertados en la tabla bienes_control en un solo registro en una sola fila o renglón.

El trigger que se indica al inicio tal cual como esta codificado, hace su función, solo que inserta un valor en el campo de la tabla indicado, y luego rellena con ceros varios renglones, luego inserta otro campo y así se sigue hasta terminar de copiar los campos indicados generando una "tablota" de datos inservible.

Hice una modificación el día de ayer al Trigger dejándolo de esta manera:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insertar_control AFTER UPDATE ON bienes
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

     IF NEW.Cotejado == 1
     THEN

    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Activo = NEW.Activo;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET SubActivo = NEW.SubActivo;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Numero_Empleado = NEW.Numero_Empleado;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Empleado_Movimiento = NEW.Empleado_Movimiento;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Cotejado = NEW.Cotejado;
    INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Proceso = NEW.Proceso;

    END If;

  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Y el  resultado obtenido que se muestra desde phpmyadmin:
[image: Vista del resultado]

Como se puede observar me genera ahora 7 registros o renglones, lo que necesito es que todos estos campos queden solo renglon en su respectivo campo.

Comment: Lo que te está pasando es la consecuencia de utilizar `INSERT` en vez de `UPDATE`: cada `INSERT` es un nuevo registro, que es lo que estás obteniendo.

Comment: David, entonces si cambio los INSERT por UPDATE haría digamos un loop de update con  cada campo hasta que termine y me lo dejaría todo en un registro..

Comment: Tendrás que hacer un `INSERT` para el primero, pero el resto con `UPDATE` exacto, como en la respuesta que te he pasado

Comment: Ok deja modificar en base a tus sugerencias.  GRacias!!!!

Comment: No, que voy a implementar lo que me comentas de hacer primero un INSERT y posteriormente los uPDATES basado en el trigger que amablemente me has compartido.  Solo que primero tengo que hacer un reporte de mi trabajo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando parece ser algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertar_control AFTER UPDATE ON bienes
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.Cotejado!=OLD.Cotejado AND NEW.Proceso!=OLD.Proceso THEN
      INSERT INTO bienes_control (Id_Bien) VALUES (NEW.Id_Bien);
      IF NEW.Activo!=OLD.Activo THEN
        UPDATE bienes_control SET Activo=NEW.Activo 
          WHERE Id_Bien=NEW.Id_Bien;
      END IF;
      IF NEW.SubActivo!=OLD.SubActivo THEN
        UPDATE bienes_control SET SubActivo=NEW.SubActivo 
          WHERE Id_Bien=NEW.Id_Bien;
      END IF;
      IF NEW.Numero_Empleado!=OLD.Numero_Empleado THEN
        UPDATE bienes_control SET Numero_Empleado=NEW.Numero_Empleado 
          WHERE Id_Bien=NEW.Id_Bien;
      END IF;
      IF NEW.Empleado_Movimiento!=OLD.Empleado_Movimiento THEN
        UPDATE bienes_control SET Empleado_Movimiento=NEW.Empleado_Movimiento 
          WHERE Id_Bien=NEW.Id_Bien;
      END IF;
      IF NEW.Cotejado!=OLD.Cotejado THEN
        UPDATE bienes_control SET Cotejado=NEW.Cotejado 
          WHERE Id_Bien=NEW.Id_Bien;
      END IF;
      IF NEW.Proceso!=OLD.Proceso THEN
        UPDATE bienes_control SET Proceso=NEW.Proceso 
          WHERE Id_Bien=NEW.Id_Bien;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Para el dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE bienes(
  Id_Bien int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Activo varchar(63),
  SubActivo varchar(63),
  Numero_Empleado int,
  Empleado_Movimiento int,
  Cotejado bool,
  Proceso int
  );
CREATE TABLE bienes_control(
  Id_Bien int,
  Activo varchar(63),
  SubActivo varchar(63),
  Numero_Empleado int,
  Empleado_Movimiento int,
  Cotejado bool,
  Proceso int
  );
INSERT INTO bienes (
    Activo,SubActivo,Numero_Empleado,
    Empleado_Movimiento,Cotejado,Proceso
  ,Id_Bien) VALUES ('A','S',1,1,1,1);
```

Por cada `UPDATE` en `bienes` en los que se modifique simultáneamente `Cotejado` y `Proceso`, crea un nuevo registro en `bienes_control` con todos los campos a `NULL` excepto aquellos que también hayan sido modificados.

Como indicas, habrá un registro por cada cambio.

Espero que sea lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta de la forma más ajustada a tu cuestión.

Comment: Buenos días, agradezco tu aportación , ya carge las tablas , y bueno ya no se si sea una falla de mi phpmyadmin, que de todo me envia errores, me indica que hay un error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4   y bueno de entrada a simple vista no le veo problema en la sintaxis pero habre de revisar

Comment: Estuve revisando las sentencias, y estoy entendiendo que indican en general, que si encuentra un valor diferente en algún campo en bienes, entonces replica este cambio en bienes_control , pero solo copia el cambio hecho y lo demas queda null ?

Comment: Exacto, ¿no era eso es lo que pedías?

Comment: En este sentido creo que yo fui el que cometio una omision al redactar, el trigger que tengo indicado al inicio hace su funcion, si pero no del todo bien, lo que intente hacer era que al momento que los campos Cotejado y Proceso fueran actualizados simultaneamente , entonces el trigger hiciera una copia de ciertos campos de la tabla bienes a la de bienes control. pero que esto lo haga en un solo registro, y no escalonado que es como lo ejecuta ese trigeer

Comment: Claro, es que, de momento en Stackoverflow, adivinos aún no somos... :) Modifica la pregunta con especificaciones concretas y modificaré la respuesta acorde a éstas. Por lo que comentas, no parece complicado. Ya me dices

Comment: Listo David  añadí un cambio que hice ayer al trigger, y el resultado que obtengo lo muestro en una imagen, lo que no logre hacer es que el resultado me saliera en un solo renglón - fila - registro.  Saludos

Comment: En la pregunta modificada no especificas qué campos quieres registrar después de modificar simulatáneamente `cotejado` y `proceso`. Te modifico la respuesta con todos ya ya me dices si es lo que necesitabas

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunas modificaciones y me quedo esto:

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER insertar_control AFTER UPDATE ON bienes
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

```
 IF NEW.Cotejado == 1
 THEN
 INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Activo = NEW.Activo;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET SubActivo = NEW.SubActivo;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Numero_Empleado = NEW.Numero_Empleado;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Empleado_Movimiento = NEW.Empleado_Movimiento;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Cotejado = NEW.Cotejado;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Proceso = NEW.Proceso
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;

END If;
```

END;
|

delimiter ;

Para un registro que se actualiza desde bienes funciona muy bien, pero si tengo otro update posterior el insert me mezcla datos de la tabla origen en la tabla destino.

Sigo revisando como mejorar esto.

Saludos

Comment: Necesitas un `WHERE` por cada `UPDATE`, de lo contrario cada `UPDATE` te modificará todos los registros de `bienes_contral`. Pasa igual que con el `DELETE FROM` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_cVJgIz_Cs

Comment: ok Gracias David, ya te estare comentando como va, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y consejos.  Buen fin de Semana!!!

Comment: Por favor, no agregues respuestas mas alla de la respuesta aceptada, ya que solo generan ruido. Mas si pones mas de una respuesta, no se entiende en realidad cual es la respuesta que ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

finalmente asi quedo mi trigger por si a alguien le es de utilidad.

```html
BEGIN

 IF NEW.Cotejado != 0 AND NEW.Proceso != 0
 THEN
 INSERT INTO bienes_control SET Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Activo = NEW.Activo
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 END IF;
     
 IF NEW.Cotejado != 0 AND NEW.Proceso != 0
 THEN
 UPDATE bienes_control SET SubActivo = NEW.SubActivo
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 END IF;
     
 IF NEW.Cotejado != 0 AND NEW.Proceso != 0
 THEN
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Numero_Empleado = NEW.Numero_Empleado
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 END IF;
 
 IF NEW.Cotejado != 0 AND NEW.Proceso != 0
 THEN
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Empleado_Movimiento = NEW.Empleado_Movimiento
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 END IF;
 
 IF NEW.Cotejado != 0 AND NEW.Proceso != 0
 THEN
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Cotejado = NEW.Cotejado
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 END IF;
 
 IF NEW.Cotejado != 0 AND NEW.Proceso != 0
 THEN
 UPDATE bienes_control SET Proceso = NEW.Proceso
 WHERE Id_Bien = NEW.Id_Bien;
 END IF;
     
END
```

Gracias por sus aportaciones.